# Entity Framework separating clustered index from primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design

I have a table schema where the primary key is a `uniqueidentifier`, and the clustered index is an identity column of type `bigint`.

The idea is that the Guid index is likely going to be fragmented and if it's going to be fragmented I prefer that it's not the clustered index because then it would really slow down insert. Ie I want the row inserted sequentially as much as possible.

However I do NOT want the clustered index propagated to the conceptual layer in EF. The clustered index is simply the physical location of the so said record and the programmers don't need to know anything about it. As far as they are concerned they are only dealing with the Guid PK. So I removed the property from the models.

The project compilation complains however that the clustered index column is non nullable, and has no default value, either of which is nonsensical considering it is an identity column and can neither have a default value or be nullable.

What can I do to get the project to compile?

Note: I do not want a debate about Guid vs. Sequential Guid vs. Int Id. This system must be able to scale out and that means Guid PK where I'm concerned.

Comment: If you aren't using the bigint column for anything, how exactly is this helping you?

Comment: He is using it as the clustered index (to improve the db performance).

Comment: @ypercube This makes no sense. If you aren't querying on that column, you aren't using that index. If OP will only ever query on the GUID column this might as well be the clustered index. If there is actually a valid need for more ordered index, then a sequential GUID should be used. By adding a second index, you only increase the  time it takes to insert a row and by doing what OP suggests, (marginally) increase the time it takes to query a record.

Comment: @scottm: Here is a nice article: [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)

Comment: Does it help to you give the column a default value anyway? It will be ignored, but it may  fill the gap in the model validation.

Comment: And you can make its setter and getter private.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the property's `EntityKey` value is set to `true` in the EDMX.

Comment: I can't do that, it's not the entity key... this is what the mapping entry looks like <Property Name="ClusterId" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"  /> Everything is good there, except that EF needs to honor the StoreGeneratedPattern and stop treating it as compile time exception.

Comment: You can have multiple entity keys on a single entity.

Comment: I added the ClusterId to the EntityKey value like this: <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            <PropertyRef Name="ClusterId"/>
          </Key> inside the edmx. Doesn't seem right, and could be an issue later, should the table be dynamically sharded in the future, as the ClusterID could change, and EF will think that the entity in the cache is a different entity, when they are the same. Would prefer a cleaner solution but this is at least worth a thumb's up.

Comment: Does not work for long in a DB First solution. An update to the edmx screws everything up again.